# dynamically import class from file and use a function in it

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this file `./src/commands/test.js`:

```
export default class {
    run() {
        console.log('test!')
    }
}
```

i am trying to make a command that will get all commands in that folder and call their `run` function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs')
const folders = [
    './src/commands',
    //'./my_modules/diontron/unity/src/commands',
]

folders.forEach(folder => {
    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file != 'index.js') {
                let commandClass = require(folder + '/' + file).default
                let command = new commandClass()

                command.run()
            }
        })
    })
})
```

this gives me the error:

```
Cannot find module './src/commands/test.js'
```

how do i dynamically go through all files in a folder, require/import them, and use the class function?

Comment: Why are you mixing CommonJS and ESM?

Comment: I can't replicate the error you've described. I get *other* errors (because of the CommonJS/ESM thing), but not that error. Please update the question with more complete information, including where this bash script is located, whether it's in the path, what your `package.json` file(s) contains/contain, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't know, i really want to just use ESM for everything...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it looks like node uses CommonJS but i just want to use ES, this is just confusing

Comment: See: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with dynamic `import()` rather than `require`. Note that you'll need a `package.json` in `src` or `src/commands` with `"type": "module"` in it, since `test.js` uses ESM by Node.js uses CommonJS by default.

This works for me in that setup:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const fs = require("fs");
const folders = [
    "./src/commands",
    //"./my_modules/diontron/unity/src/commands",
];

folders.forEach(folder => {
    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file != "index.js") {
                const modFile = folder + "/" + file;
                import(modFile)
                .then(({ default: commandClass }) => {
                    const command = new commandClass();
                    command.run();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(`Failed to load module ${modFile}`);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Although that runs the code in parallel. If you want to run it in series (each waiting for the previous one to complete), you might do this (note the change from `"fs"` to `"fs/promises"` at the top):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const fs = require("fs/promises");
const folders = [
    "./src/commands",
    //"./my_modules/diontron/unity/src/commands",
];

(async () => {
    for (const folder of folders) {
        for (const folder of folders) {
            const files = await fs.readdir(folder);
            for (const file of files) {
                const { default: commandClass } = await import(folder + "/" + file);
                const command = new commandClass();
                command.run();
            }
        }
    }
})()
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

That relies on the script being run from the parent folder of the folders you're searching. If you want to use the current path instead, you should use `process.cwd()` to get it, then use that to resolve the folders:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path"); // ***
const folders = [
    "./src/commands",
    //"./my_modules/diontron/unity/src/commands",
];

const currentDir = process.cwd(); // ***

folders.forEach(folder => {
    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        const fullFolder = path.join(currentDir, folder); // ***
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file != "index.js") {
                const modFile = fullFolder + "/" + file; // ***
                import(modFile)
                .then(({ default: commandClass }) => {
                    const command = new commandClass();
                    command.run();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(`Failed to load module ${modFile}`);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, i figured out how to use `fs` by converting to `.mjs`, now i have a new problem lol. `import(folder + '/' + file)` fails in the `forEach` because it seems like the command path uses the root path, but i can't use that in the `import`

Comment: @diontron - You probably want to use `process.cwd()` to get the current directory, then resolve the folder relative to that. I've updated with an example.